# What Java actually stores inside Keystore when generating Keys?

Tags: encryption

When we use `Keytool` to generate a `Keystore` to store Private/Public keys, what Java actually stores inside the Keystore file ?

I have observed that `Keytool` asks for the `keypass` and `alias` to generate the key, the `alias` can be used to retrieve any key from the `keystore` given that correct `keypass` is provided.

So, what actually stores inside a keystore file ?

1) an actual key ? 
or
2)  the pair of `keypass` and `alias`, and the key is generated using that keypass/alias ?

What I think is, the `keypass` and `alias` are stored in the keystore and key is generated if correct data is provided, am I correct ? , If not, and Raw key is stored inside a keystore then what is the need of `keypass` at first place ?

For your convenience, here is more detail about `keytool`,

> Java Keytool is a key and certificate management utility. It allows
>   users to manage their own public/private key pairs and certificates.
>   It also allows users to cache certificates. Java Keytool stores the
>   keys and certificates in what is called a keystore. By default the
>   Java keystore is implemented as a file. It protects private keys with
>   a password. A Keytool keystore contains the private key and any
>   certificates necessary to complete a chain of trust and establish the
>   trustworthiness of the primary certificate.

### Parameters of `keytool` command

### Keystore Parameters

**genseckey**
Generate SecretKey. This is the flag indicating the creation of a synchronous key which will become our AES key

**keystore**
Location of the keystore. If the keystore does not exist, the tool will create a new store. Paths can be relative or absolute but must be local

**storetype**
this is the type of store (JCE, PK12, JCEKS, etc). JCEKS is used to store symmetric keys (AES) not contained within a certificate.

**storepass**
password related to the keystore. Highly recommended to create a strong passphrase for the keystore

**Key Parameters**

**keyalg**
algorithm used to create the key (AES/DES/etc)

**keysize**
size of the key (128, 192, 256, etc)

**alias**
alias given to the newly created key in which to reference when using the key

**keypass**
password protecting the use of the key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nitpick: `keytool` *accepts* both alias and keypass if specified; if not specified it *prompts* for key password if needed but defaults alias to `mykey`. A JCEKS file can be operated on either by `keytool` or by other code. 
JCEKS can support three types of entries: privateKey, trustedCert, and secretKey (the older and default JKS file can do the first two).

The operations and algorithms you ask about are "symmetric" (not "synchronous") and use a "secret" key NOT "public" and "private" keys which apply to algorithms like RSA, DSA, ECC.
Also symmetric keys including AES are NEVER in certificates.

A secretKey entry *contains* the secretkey **encrypted using the keypassword** (using a PBE aka key-stretching algorithm). The password itself is not stored, which would be totally insecure, and instead must be *provided* on any attempt to access the privatekey. Note that you can change the alias of a secretkey entry and/or re-encrypt with a different keypassword without changing the key.